# Swing apps doesn't run

Tags: java, swing, runtime-error, illegalargumentexception

I have a problem in using swing. I don't know what is the cause of this but i'm just trying to create a simple frame app using swing at it give me a lot of error.

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class StacksGui {
public static void main(String args[]) 
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setSize(100,200);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

---

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.createGlassPane(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at StacksGui.main(StacksGui.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 incompatible with Text-specific LCD contrast key
    at java.awt.RenderingHints.put(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.getDesktopAAHints(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getDesktopAAHints(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getDesktopFontHints(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopProperties.getProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.updateProperties(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyInitWProps(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: This seems to be incomplete. The stack trace indicates you have a main method but it's not shown.

Comment: sorry! i forgot to put my main but still my output is still the same. A lot of error.

Comment: Your code needs to be in a method. It is *only* in a class right now. Please read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert It is probably a copy and paste error. The OP should fix it but the stack trace indicates their actual code is compilable.

Comment: I reinstall my jdk but still it produces the same output.

Comment: Googling the 'incompatible with LCD key' seems to indicate its a cleartype compatibility issue. Is it the latest JDK, and are you running a stable graphics card driver?

Comment: Here is a similar bug report: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6503988 As @Petesh says it seems to have something to do with ClearType fonts. The bug report indicates it should require the registry to be altered manually (for the most part) for this exception to be thrown. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the latest jdk and i'm running a stable graphics driver.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem when all java Swing apps crashed silently.
After trying to launch from command line got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 181193932 incompatible with Text-specific LCD contrast key
```

As it's said in [JDK-6503988](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6503988), the problem is connected with [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType) registry setting [FontSmoothingGamma](https://superuser.com/questions/737922/how-to-improve-subpixel-hinting-in-windows-7/945614#945614).

This can be fixed by running "[Adjust ClearType text](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28790/tweak-cleartype-in-windows-7/)" from Control panel (`cttune.exe`) or by [changing the registry](https://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd) directly:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /t REG_DWORD /v FontSmoothingGamma /d 1024 /f
```

A reboot may be needed for changes to take the effect.

See also a 10-year-old investigation of the same problem at https://www.rarst.net/software/cleartype-install4j-java-bug/.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(100,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

I only see a difference at

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

where I added the frame. However your stacktrace looks like there's another error, so first try this and if it still don't work, give us a bit more code to look at.

Comment: This should be a comment. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid

Comment: @Radiodef: you cannot paste that long code as comment, so it is fine, especially since the OP may just pick up this working code. I accidentally flagged is NAA instead o deemed invalid, so the moderator reviewing this, please consider that. :)