# Latest Android Studio 3.6.3 not running after installation in windows 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I installed the latest  android studio 64bit version on windows 10, but it is not launching after installation. I checked the task manager, when i double click the studio icon, it appears in task manager for 5 seconds and then disappears. I also tried running as administrator, didn't work. I have already set JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables and path variable for jdk and jre. Please help!!

On running studio.bat, i get the following error : 
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin>studio.bat

```
ERROR - #com.intellij.idea.Main - Cannot initialize default LaF
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$addInitUiTasks$9(StartupUtil.java:284)
```

Thanx in advance for all the suggestions :).

Comment: Try reinstalling and deleting the configuration, see the generic steps at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to my problem. It was because Java Swing was not causing exception because "ClearType text" was enabled on my Windows laptop. Go to adjust cleartype text and it will work like a charm !!!

Also see this post :
[Swing apps doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444846/swing-apps-doesnt-run)

Comment: Thanx, that's really helpful!